# Class namespace?

Tags: c++, oop, lang

Is it me or the implementation of object oriented paradigm in C++ is missing the concept of class namespace?

Here is an example of what I mean:

> Document { Header {} Body {} Footer {} }

Document is an object that can have a header, body, and footer.

A straight forward way to address such object and its elements from external namespace is

- Document
- Document::Header
- Document::Body
- Document::Footer

Is there a way to achieve such naming structure in C++ without imposing a restriction on the definition of Document class?

1) namespace Document { ... }

This case requires an object class inside its own namespace and using Document::Document seems redundant and unintended.

2) namespace Document { class ... } typedef Document::Document document;

This case gives document and Document::{part}, which in case sensitive language may seem weird and unrelated.

3) class Document { class ... };

This case requires including Document header in definition of every nested class and doesn't allow to make the final object be a derivative of its parts, since they are defined within its own scope.

4) class document { class ... }; class Document : public document {}

This case is close to what is intended but costs an extra class and inheritance.

!) Ideally, what I'd like to have is

```
namespace class Document {

class Header;
class Body;
class Footer;

class Document; // linked with the parent namespace as with its own name space

}

Document doc; // ok, resolves Document as a class
Document::{Part} docPart; // ok, resolves Document as namespace
```

.) Is there any other reasonable way to achieve what is intended without unreasonable extra cost?

I'm also not exactly sure why such trivial things are not a standard way to do it. :/ Any specific reason?

**--- clarification ---**

To address some of the raised questions,

"What is it useful for?" 1) Plain language 2) Transparent mapping from a language construct to an object's abstract model and vice versa.

"Why would one want to derive an object from its parts?" Not every entity introduced by an object has to be its part. It can be its essence, for example. E.g.:

> Document { Skeleton{} Parts { Header {} Body {} Footer {} } }

**--- abstract framework ---**

Think of an object as a module whose definition may use external symbols and introduce some of its own along with the definition of its own logical entity, to which they should remain related since it introduces them.

**--- point ---**

The whole module is a definition of an object. It would be nice to be able to use it as such without any additional linguistic ridicules.

=== resolution ===

Thank you for your feedback.

Until there is a way in C++ to link a namespace name to a class, I guess I'll use the

> *ObjectName* { ... Object {} } -> *ObjectName*::Object, *ObjectName*::*Part*

construct in such cases. It may be not as short as I'd like to, but at least transparent enough, with no extra cost, and can be used with forward declarations.

Comment: "This case is close to what is intended but costs an extra class and inheritance."

Why do you think this is a problem? It appears to accurately model what you need?

Comment: Okay, cool, and what is this useful for?

Comment: Aren't you, like, mixing up HTML with C++ n'stuff?

Comment: Use nested classes as MadKeithV proposes.

Comment: What is the differences between case 3 and 4? The drawbacks of case 4 is just the same as you list in case 3, but instead of requiring the header for the `Document` class you just move it to the header of the `document` class (which should probably be named `DocumentBase` or similar to avoid confusion).

Comment: *"Is it me or the implementation of object oriented paradigm in C++ is missing the concept of class namespace?"* - No it's not you. Strangely enough, C++'s implementation of the object-oriented paradigm is missing many concepts (of questionable usefulness) known from completely different languages ;) I'm not even sure the "hardcore-OO" languages like Java or C# have this concept (but I might be wrong on that). And of course you know that inheritance and an extra class doesn't cost anything when trying to map concepts to a language not exposing them natively.

Comment: Nested class or inheritance. Choice is yours!

Answer (score 6):

Your third option - using nested class declarations / definitions, will get you the ideal scope resolution as you want (though it will not involve a single namespace).

```
class Document 
  {
  public:
    class Header
      {
      // Header class declaration here
      };

    class Body
      {
      // Body class declaration here
      };

   class Footer
      {
      // Footer class declaration here
      };

    // Document declaration here.
  };
```

Your concerns with that option are:

**Requires including Document header in definition of every nested class**

Yes - the nested classes are inextricably linked to the surrounding class, their implementations will depend on the definition of the surrounding class because it contains the definitions of the nested classes.  This is unavoidable.

**Dpesn't allow to make the final object be a derivative of its parts, since they are defined within its own scope.**

What you are trying to do seems to make very little logical sense - you are trying to define something based on its own parts, which is a circular definition.  What are you trying to achieve by deriving Document from Header, Body or Footer?

The final line of your question suggests that you find your desired functionality "trivial", but in my opinion and experience it is far from trivial. You seem to be conflating a namespace and a class because of syntactical similarities, but they are entirely different concepts.  You have to separate the two in your mind, they have very little overlap besides some scoping effects and scope resolution syntax.  Your "Document" must be either a namespace and a class.  Pick one ;)  (technically it's actually possible to have both a namespace Document and a class Document, but this is likely to be a source of confusion.
)

Comment: @MadKeithV, in my mind, there would be no confusion if Document namespace had class attribute. - Think of an object as a module, it may use external symbols and introduce some of its own, but essentially, it's an object, whose definition should have a scope both for introduced symbols and its own logical entity. And outside of that module, there could be a way to use it as an object without a ridicule imposed by a language. - In other words, namespace and class are different when the language they come from tells that they are different. In my mind, everything is an object\module. :)

Comment: @inx - there may be no confusion in your mind, but I have no idea what you mean.  An object isn't a module.  Objects, classes, modules and namespaces are all *different concepts*.

Comment: @MadKeithV, think of a human body. It has head and hands and such. They all are parts of definition of a body. Body is an object, which along with instances similar to it can be generalized to a class (of objects). To define that object through its class definition, one can think of it as a module that should include the definition of its parts, which can be wrapped into a namespace, and compiled to produce let's say a java module or c++ lib. - They may be different concepts, but they are all intended to express things\objects\logic through other things\objects\logical entities.

Answer (score 2):

Your first case does exactly what you say you want. There's nothing redundant about `Document::Document` -- it refers to the `Document` class in the `Document` namespace. There might very well be a Document class in the `XML` namespace, and another one in the `MyCompany` namespace.

Your second case looks like an attempt to essentially defeat the purpose of using namespaces. If you don't want to use a namespace, don't -- just use the global (unspecified) namespace and risk collisions. If you only want to avoid the `Document::` part in the code that's related to your `Document` class, add a `using namespace Document` directive in that code.

Comment: While I am not a fan of using the same name for a class and a namespace, the concept of grouping classes inside a logical related  namespace (I'd probably use lowercase document here) is of course very sound.

Comment: @MadKeithV I agree, but not because of some possibility of confusion -- it's just not very descriptive. If a class name tells you what a class *is*, the namespace name should tell you *where it came from*, and the two probably aren't the same. However, that's the example the OP gave, so I thought I'd stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

> 3) class Document { class ... };
>
> This case requires including Document header in definition of every nested class and doesn't allow to make the final object be a derivative of its parts, since they are defined within its own scope.

No, this design is what makes the most sense. I don't understand what you think the difference would be between `class` and `namespace class`.

```
class Document
{
public:
    class Header
    {
    };

    Header m_header;

    class Body
    {
    };

    Body m_Body;
};
```

What's wrong with this design? You access the types via `Document::Header`. You access via instances like `myDocument.m_header`.

The only inherent oddness is that you can't name a type and member variable the same, but there are plenty of ways around that and it's a superficial restriction really.

Comment: I'd change it to `class { } Header;`

Comment: "What's wrong with this design?" The naming convention:-).  The nested classes should be `Header`, etc., and the member variables `myHeader`, `m_header` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

You just enclose the part classes within the `Document` class.

```
class Document {
public:
   class Header;
   class Body;
   class Footer;
};
```

You can validly use this:

```
Document myDoc;   // Type Document
Document::Header myHeader;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because a `Document` *object* contains a `Header` *object* doesn’t mean that the `Header` *class* should be contained in the `Document` *class*. At least, that’s not usually done.

I would nest classes only in rare instances; namely, when the nested class is an implementation detail of the outer class, and isn’t exposed to the outside world (but even then it’s common to forego nesting).

This, by the way, is independent of C++: classes in general are rarely nested except to hide implementation details. Frameworks to model object relations as in your case wouldn’t normally use nesting. Instead, you might have something like this:

```
namespace Html {
    class Document;
    class Header;
    class Body;
    // …
}
```

C++ in particular uses flat namespace hierarchies but the above would equally apply to C# or Java.

Finally, to explicitly address your introductory question:

> Is it me or the implementation of object oriented paradigm in C++ is missing the concept of class namespace?

C+ has this concept to the same extent as other modern OO languages: a class forms a namespace for the purpose of name lookup so you *can* achieve what you want. But for the reason mentioned above I don’t think it’s a particularly desirable goal.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me how much you want to expose the nested
classes, but if they are part of `Document`, they probably should be
nested classes.  Your example of what you mean, at the start of your
code, is exactly how one would do this in C++:

```
class Document
{
public:  //  or not?
    class Header
    {
    };
    class Body
    {
    };
    class Footer
    {
    };
};
```

About the only objection I can see is that implementation files only
concerned with `Document::Header` must include the entire `Document`
class definition, but I don't think this is a major problem; if
`Document::Header` really isn't independent, then it seems reasonable to
require this.  With regards to your second objection to this solution:
you never want to make an object derive from its parts: a `Document`
*hasA* `Header`; it isn't an *isA* relationship.

If it does make sense for `Header` et al to be used separately, then the
best solution is to define them outside of the `Document` class, either
giving them more descriptive names (e.g. `DocumentHeader`) or wrapping
them in a special namespace (e.g. `namespace DocumentParts`).  Depending
on their relationship with `Document`, it might make sense to use
`typedef` in `Document` so that they can be referred to as either
`DocumentParts::Header` or `Document::Header`.